# Problems with iImplementing jQuery into a wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to implement some jquery scripts into my Wordpress plugin, but I keep getting the error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

In my console. I've tried enqueue'ing jquery in my plugin itself but that isn't helping either. This is the code I'm using.

```
function sale_price_change() {
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
            (function($) {  
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(".products .outofstock a .price").text("' . get_option('soldout_label_price') . '");
                    });
                })(jQuery);
</script>
';
}
add_action( 'init', 'sale_price_change' );
```

The code itself has worked before but somehow I still keep getting this error. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You have to make sure that jQuery itself is imported in the page before any code that uses it.

Comment: I checked the source, the script is indeed put before any library that is added. How could I make it so that jQuery is the first thing added to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really consider properly enqueueing these scripts (by putting your custom JS in an external .js file). Another way to do this would be to enqueue jQuery in the [`wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts), and then your scripts in [`wp_footer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer):

```
function so_34315785_enqueue_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_34315785_enqueue_jquery' );

function so_34315785_print_scripts() {
    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($) {  
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(".products .outofstock a .price").text("' . get_option("soldout_label_price") . '");
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    ';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'so_34315785_print_scripts', 25 );
```

Comment: Changing it to wp_footer doesn't seem to work, the script doesn't get printed at all. Any ideas?

And the reason that I'm hesitant in putting it in a external .js file is because I need to get an variable from the .php file, if there would be a way to transfer the variable I could try though.

Comment: Ok wait, it seems to work on normal pages, even the variables get passed through and I can reach the media library again. Only now it isn't activated  in the back-end. I have a "set back to default" button in my options, only it Isn't working now that the jQuery is only activated on the front end.

Comment: Commenting to myself again. Apparently Admin_footer is a thing. It all seems to work now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

you could just include jquery i guess? Maybe not super bueautiful solution though

```
function sale_price_change() {
echo '
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            (function($) {  
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(".products .outofstock a .price").text("' . get_option('soldout_label_price') . '");
                    });
                })(jQuery);
</script>
';
}
add_action( 'init', 'sale_price_change' );
```

Comment: Well, it fixes the problem but gives me a different problem. I actually used this method before (That's why I said I knew the code worked) but somehow it messes my media library.
I can't upload or see images anymore with this fix, any idea why this weird connection happens?

Comment: maybe its related to the version of jQuery? Try to include the same version that your media library uses

Comment: I've changed the version but no change sadly enough.

Comment: well, an option is to rewrite that part in pure JS, so you dont need jQuery (attach the event, select the elements, and set the text)